# Sons of a cursed man

Tags: sin, curse, canaan, question

Even if a man is cursed like Cain or Canaan, can he have righteous sons?

Did Cain have righteous sons?

Comment: Adam was cursed. He himself was righteous, as were/are many of his descendants. Cain had no righteous descendants recorded in the Torah.

Comment: Korach's children seem have done OK.

Comment: @rosends Sure, but it doesn't actually say the word "cursed" about Korach the way it does about Cain or Canaan.

Comment: @RabbiKaii It doesn't say the word "cursed" about Adam himself, just that the earth was cursed because of him. Whereas by Cain it actually says ארור אתה, and similarly by Canaan ארור כנען.

Comment: @Meir good point. I VTC though because there doesn't seem to be any reason to think that someone who is cursed can't have righteous descendants. Curse isn't defined but what you just said at least helps and should be in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> הַרְבֵּה בָּנִים הָיוּ לוֹ לִכְנַעַן שֶׁרְאוּיִין לִיסָּמֵךְ כְּטָבִי עַבְדּוֹ שֶׁל רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל
>
> Canaan had many descendants who would have deserved to be ordained with semichah, like Tavi, the slave of Rabban Gamliel

([Yoma 87a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.87a.5?lang=he))

> אֱלִיעֶזֶר הוּא כְּנַעַן וְעַל יְדֵי שֶׁשִּׁמֵּשׁ אוֹתוֹ צַדִּיק יָצָא מִכְּלַל אָרוּר וּבָא לִכְלַל בָּרוּךְ, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (בראשית ט, כה): וַיֹּאמֶר אָרוּר כְּנָעַן, וּכְתִיב (בראשית כד, לא): בּוֹא בְּרוּךְ ה'
>
> Eliezer is Canaan, and by serving that tzaddik (Avraham), he left the category of "cursed" and entered the category of "blessed." Thus it says "He said, 'Cursed is Canaan,'" and it says [about Eliezer], "Come, blessed one of Hashem."

([Vayikra Rabbah 17:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.17.5?lang=he))

> ועוד מעשה היה ברבן גמליאל, שהיו הזקנים מסובין אצלו, והיה טבי עבדו עומד ומשמשו. אמר רבי אלעזר בן עזריה: אי לך כנען שחייבת לבנייך, בין הצדיקים ובין הרשעים! בדין הוא שיהא טבי מיסב ואני משמשו
>
> It happened that the Elders were reclining at Rabban Gamliel's house, and his slave Tavi was standing and serving. Said R. Elazar ben Azariah: Woe to you, Canaan, that you made your children liable, whether righteous or wicked! By rights Tavi ought to be reclining, and I would be serving him!

([Midrash Mishlei 9:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Mishlei.9?vhe=%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_-_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A8&lang=he))